# Need help identifying why my Theano scripts won't run

Tags: python, ipython, theano, jupyter-notebook, keras

Theano scripts won't run.  For example, I tried running the following code in Jupyter Notebook but I get a message saying that my kernel has died.  Restarting the kernel doesn't help either.  The error isn't exclusive to just this script, but any script I attempt to run using Theano.

Here is the exact error message:

> The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically."

I'm using Anaconda, with python 2.7.11, 64bit.  The issue arises on both CPU and GPU.

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T

# Basic expressions and calculus
x = T.dscalar('x')
y = T.dscalar('y')
z = x*x + y*y
f = theano.function([x,y], z)
```

Summary of theano settings:

Float32, CPU

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a problem with the Theano installation.  Try uninstalling and then installing the bleeding-edge version (`pip install git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git`) and see if you still get the issue.